# Centos: Obtain MAC address of a local machine

Tags: centos, networking, ip, macintosh

I have a local network with many machines. From a CentOS server I need to obtain the MAC address of specific IP (and need to automate this for several hundred IPs).

I have tried ping + arp -a, but it doesn't keep track of this IP it seems.

```
ping -c 3 10.101.2.11
PING 10.101.2.11 (10.101.2.11) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.101.2.11: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.531 ms
64 bytes from 10.101.2.11: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=0.564 ms
64 bytes from 10.101.2.11: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=0.576 ms

--- 10.101.2.11 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.531/0.557/0.576/0.019 ms

$ arp -a
? (10.1.0.101) at xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx [ether] on eth0
? (10.1.0.11) at xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx [ether] on eth0
gateway (10.1.0.1) at xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx [ether] on eth0
? (10.1.0.102) at xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx [ether] on eth0
```

On other OS `arp-scan` might be a solution to obtain the MAC of the device, but on CentOS the output is simply:

```
$: arp-scan 10.101.2.11
Interface: eth0, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
Starting arp-scan 1.9.2 with 1 hosts (http://www.nta-monitor.com/tools-resources/security-tools/arp-scan/)
4 packets received by filter, 0 packets dropped by kernel
Ending arp-scan 1.9.2: 1 hosts scanned in 1.815 seconds (0.55 hosts/sec). 0 responded
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see in your arp -a command output is shows a 10.1.0 address and your ping has a 10.101.2 they are on different networks. arp will be for the local network you are on.

Now ip neigh is the new arp -a and has the same behaviour. 
You will have to get on that subnet to see the mac and subnet info from those computers.

Can you ssh into it? If so you can send remote command and get arp from there if you have credentials on that machine.

```
ssh username@10.101.2.11 `ip neigh`
```

I haven't used arp-scan however from looking at the documentation it states scans the local network. It appears the computer your trying to get a mac on is in another subnet.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your targets live on a different network. You are told that 10.1.0.1 is gateway, as it doesn't give the target's (IPs 10.101.x.x) MAC addresses, they are probably on a different network. Having addresses from 10.1.0.1 to 10.101.0.0 would mean some 600 thousand machines on a network...

Find out what the network setup is (network masks, routers, ...).